# Multi part file uploading method

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, chunked, http-content-range

Im trying to upload faster. My connection upload limit is ~2Mbit and upload speed is ~200Kb. When i try to upload 10Mb file, it finished ~50 secs. I want to do faster.

Is there any method like that multi part file uploading. For example process:

1. Select file (10000Kb)
2. Submit form
3. Split into pieces the file (100kb x 100 pieces)
4. Upload them all at once
5. Merge pieces and save the file

This upload method is possible? I read about `Content-Range` and `Chunked file uploads` but i did not know exactly where to look.

Is that may guide me in this regard? Or does anyone know of an alternative fast upload method?

[image]

Comment: if you have 2Mbit limit you can upload at most 250KBs, in the perfect condition. That is your limit, and there is nothing you can do to go faster than that... AFAIK.

Comment: @Masiorama I uploaded same file(10Mb) in 4-5 seconds on different a website. So how is it possible? I tried on facebook and it finished in 12 seconds. It is impossible like your said. Right?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible. It is mathematics here, not direct experience. 2Mbit / 8bit equals 250KB, so you can upload at most 1MB every 4 seconds. Otherwise at least one of the data you gave is false/wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Jumploader does partitioned uploads. I'm not quite sure, if these are simultaneous or not.

http://jumploader.com/